# Is nested ThemeProvider a good practice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

First of all, I'm using Material-UI v5. That is with Emotion instead of JSS.

This is my [webpage](https://mwskwong.com/). As you can see there are sections of the page which has a dark background, which is essentially using a dark theme.

Currently, I'm using the following way to override the default light theme.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={lightTheme}>
      <section>
        Section with light background
      </section>
      <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}> // override the light theme
        <section>
          Section with dark background
        </section>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

The official document does have this usage as an example, but I worry about the performance.

In the upcoming [official page](https://next.material-ui.com/branding/about/) of Material-UI, I see a similar design. Yet, instead of nested `ThemeProvider`, it simply wraps the dark content in a `Box` and overrides the style directly.

**So, which method do you think has better practice, or do you have an even better suggestion?**

For me, the former seems to have a better structure and easier to maintain, but I worry about the performance, given I have quite a few dark sections. While the latter appears to be the opposite.

Comment: Nesting providers is the most straight-forward way to do this, so I see no reason to avoid it until you can prove it causes performance issues. It should be fine unless you are dynamically updating themes a lot. Make sure your themes are static and it should be fine.

Comment: Themes are indeed static.

Comment: It's a good thing to be mindful of, but a ThemeProvider from Emotion or Styled Components etc. are just React Context providers. They're designed to be used like this, I think you'll be fine, especially just for your portfolio.

Remember its pretty trivial to test rendering perf with DevTools — do a few recordings and dive into the results to see what's going on under the hood!